# C++ `typedef Ptr<Layer>(*Constructor)(LayerParams &params);`

Tags: c++, opencv

I posted this question on OpenCV forum but since that seems to be a less active place than SO, I'm still trying to see if anyone can help me understand this line of code without much background in OpenCV source code.

Basically, I'm having trouble understanding this line of code from the OpenCV source code:

```
typedef Ptr<Layer>(*Constructor)(LayerParams &params);
```

In particular, I can't see how `typedef` work here. This seems very different from the typical `typedef unsigned long ulong;` example I saw online. Which type is being defined as which here?

If it helps, `Ptr` is a template class for smart pointers with shared ownership.

`Constructor` seems to be defined HERE in this exact code.

`LayerParams` is a data structure defined in OpenCV.

Thanks!

Comment: `Constructor` is being defined as a type that is a pointer to a function.

Comment: @NeilButterWorth Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To figure out what a `typedef` definition means, you look at what variable would be declared if the `typedef` keyword weren't there:

```
Ptr<Layer>(*Constructor)(LayerParams &params);
```

This is like a function declaration, except that in place of the function name, we have `(*Constructor)`.  This means that the variable `Constructor` is a pointer to a function.  The function it points at takes a reference to `LayerParams` as parameter, and returns a `Ptr<Layer>`.  See also the ["Clockwise Spiral Rule"](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html). (Note that page is about C. In C++ you also have lvalue reference (`&`) and rvalue reference (`&&`) tokens involved, but those work like pointer (`*`) tokens.)

So putting the `typedef` back on,

```
typedef Ptr<Layer>(*Constructor)(LayerParams &params);
```

defines the type `Constructor` to be the type of a pointer to function with parameter `LayerParams&` and return type `Ptr<Layer>`.

All this confusion is one good reason to prefer the newer `using`-style type alias syntax in new code (if it does not need to be compatible with C++03).  The same type could be defined:

```
using Constructor = Ptr<Layer>(*)(LayerParams &params);
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I figure it out now. I was confused as 1) I don't know about function pointer and 2) the order of syntax in `typedef` changes because of the use of a function pointer. The tip on using alias is also helpful - I just find it in the book "Effective Modern C++". Thanks again & I love Stackoverflow :)

Comment: @yuqli it is not true that "order of syntax in typedef changes because of the use of the function pointer".  The `using` version just moves the identifier being declared to the front, nothing else changes in the "order of syntax".

Comment: @M.M Thanks for point this out. Speaking of this, how about `typedef Ptr<Layer>(*)(LayerParams &params) Constructor`? Is this legal in defining a typedef on function pointer?

Comment: No, that's not legal. These are treated rather differently by the C++ syntax. An ordinary declaration or `typedef` definition uses a "declarator", in which function arguments (or array bounds) always come after the identifier. The part of a `using` type alias after the `=` is a "type-id" which uses an "abstract-declarator", which has no main identifier at all.

Comment: @aschepler Thanks for pointing it out. I now see it's the constraint that "function arguments (or array bounds) always come after the identifier" is what makes this `typedef` looks weird, because for non-function the identifier should come in the end, not in the middle.